# Iterate over session object on flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I would like to know if a session object in flask can be a list, e.g: I have a form where I submit a fruit, and assign it to a session variable "session['fruit']", how can I iterate over that (if possible), like when I have a normal list:

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Watermelon', 'Banana']

{% for f in fruits %}
    print(f)
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to do that with a session variable, as I already said, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The session variable, `session`, is part of the [Jinja2 context Flask provides on each request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-context). To iterate over one of its keys:

```
{% for fruit in session['fruits'] %}
  {{ fruit }}
{% endfor %}
```